# My computer cannot boot from the hard drive directly

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios

My computer had an 80GB SATA hard drive.  I replaced it with a 120GB IDE hard drive.

When I connected it to my computer and and installed Windows, it booted once, but when I shut down then restarted, I saw a boot failure message from BIOS.

My BIOS is Phoenix AwardBIOS v6.00PG.  When I boot from the boot DVD (it has a boot from hard drive option), my computer boots from the new hard drive installation.

How can I get my computer to boot from the hard drive directly?

Comment: "I saw a boot failure message from BIOS". Which message?

Comment: Look at this video: https://youtu.be/UVN0qkEyD_M

You need to switch your HDD to IDE mode

Comment: "How can I get my computer to boot from the hard drive directly?" - You are already doing that.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: failure message "DISK BOOT FAILURE,INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER"

Comment: my computer not boot from hard by bios directly but it boot from dvd ..(i have an  admin cd and it have "boot froom hard" option) after i choose this option my pc boot from hard

Comment: Can you explain to me step by step video master jay Please,